# How to create temporary procedures in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

I am currently working on a portal application for a restaurant. The backend database used is Mysql and I am using Spring JDBC support for writing data access logic.

Some of my DAOs are cluttered with multiple queries and are getting upto thousand lines of code in size. I think I can reduce the size and complexity by moving some of my logic into a SQL-PSM procedure (Since data binding and glue code in Java is an abomination from hell).

However I do not have DDL rights on the Db and hence cannot create the procedure.

I was wondering if there is a way to create a discard-able\temporary procedure that you can execute directly like a DML statement without having to create it first.

i.e. I want a procedure minus the create keyword, that would do my work, return the result and disappear.

Googled it a lot but couldn't find anything. :'( Just wondering if you folks know an elegant solution.

Comment: I don't even have a say in enabling PSMs in Db, let alone getting the team to adopt an ORM. :-( I've decided to reduce complexity by other means such as externalizing my queries into separate Spring configuration files, etc. Anyway thanks for all the replies. :-)

Comment: Have you tried Executing SQL Statements from a Text File [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-commands.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I guess you are looking for anonymous code blocks / anonymous procedures. Unfortunately it isn't supported in MySQL (it is supported in "big" RDBMSs such as Oracle or Sybase)

I would consider using some ORM framework, but I am not a Java developer, so I can't recommend any of them.

Comment: Exactly! Anonymous code blocks. Sad to hear that mysql doesn't have support for them.. :-( Wondering what to do about my spaghetti DAOs.

Comment: You can still use regular procedures to do part of the work, if you have can create them on beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can. My recommendation would be to create the "stored procedure" in Java. Write a method that takes your inputs, performs queries and calculations, then returns the dataset.

Comment: That is not the problem. I already have working code in Java. The point is that Java can't compete with SQL-PSM when it comes to data manipulation in relational tables. The code can be reduces to half its size.

Comment: @MonikaMichael You can still do the data manipulation on the DB side by running queries, right? Just wrap the queries in a Java method instead of a MySQL SP. I don't know much about the JDBC you're using, but any modern DB abstraction should include multi-query support.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for anonymous SQL blocks. But that isn't supported by MySQL.

The only workaround is to use non-anonymous SQL blocks, so standard named stored procedures and functions.