# how is parameter-value matching done when using parameters in complex queries in pyodbc?

Tags: python, parameters, mariadb, pyodbc

like say,

```
cursor.execute("select a,if(i=?,(select max(b) from tab where j=? and d in (select e from where k!=?)),10) from tabb",[10,'asasa', 'y'])
```

(of course its dirty/complex).

Is there any specific strategy used to match? Can you explain with examples?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any specific strategy used to match?

pyodbc parameters are strictly positional. The first item in the list/tuple of parameter values corresponds to the first parameter placeholder in the SQL command text. The second parameter value corresponds to the second parameter placeholder, and so on.

Named parameters are not directly supported by pyodbc, so if you have a parameter value that is used more than once you'll have to

1. repeat the parameter value in the parameters list, or
2. if your database and ODBC driver support it, use an anonymous code block to create a named variable in the SQL code (according to the rules for the dialect of SQL that you are using) and then use that variable as a parameter in your query.

Note that option (2) [does not appear to be supported by MySQL/MariaDB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9585458/2144390).

Comment: can give me an eg.

Comment: so its safe to assume that if a nth "?" in the query area will have the value at exactly nth position in the para-value specification area (**as we human read the query**). The confusion was while implementing the query (especially calculating the (inner) subqueries) certain part of the query must be implemented first.